# How can I assign a formula or function to a variable so that the formula can be entered into a cell through that variable?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, excel-formula

I want to perform yield calculations on some data and have the yield summaries be entered into a separate cell. However, I don't want to just see the results, which can be achieved by performing the calculations in the vba code and assigning the value to a variable. Instead, I want to see the formula and the referenced cells on the sheet.
For example:

I know this is possible by doing something like

`Activecell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(RC[1]:R[1]C[1])"`

What I want is to store the portion on the right of the first equals sign into a variable and then
enter that variable into a cell.

For example:

```
dim aSum as string

aSum = "=Sum(RC[1]:R[1]C[1]"
Activecell.FormulaR1C1 = aSum
```

Comment: You are missing the `")"` otherwise it should work.  What error are you getting?

Comment: To display in EXCEL the formula used to calculate a result you can use the FormulaText() function.   Let's say you drop a formula into A1 to calculate some result and you want to show that calc in B1.  Your VBA can say `Range("B1").Formula = "=FormulaText(A1)"` and you're good to go, no matter how you change your calc in A1.